# Is static friction is considered in case of trolley moving from rest position with an external force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, weight

Let us consider trolley having weight of 15 tons.Trolley has steel wheels and placed on track. Now i need to pull the trolley using winch and wheels are independent.what is force required to move trolley?i can calulate rolling friction.how to calculate the static friction required to move trolley                                                                  cosider trolley weight o.5 ton and load on trolley is 14.5 ton.                     rolling friction is less than static friction and static friction is less than maximum possible static friction.                                   How moment of inertia is calculated in this case considering above load and wheel load?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

No, the formula you mention is typically the *maximally* possible static friction. But to ensure rolling, lower than maximum static friction at the point of contact between wheel and road might be enough. You can say that $f\leq cw$, but not $f=cw$.

This means that you in general cannot find the static friction with just a simple friction formula. Static friction in its very nature simply does not follow a fixed formula but instead depends on the circumstances.

---

To answer your questions in the comments, you can try finding the necessary static friction by solving Newton's 2nd law in its rotational version:

$$\sum \tau=I\alpha,$$

where $\tau$ is torque applied to the wheel by the static friction force, $I$ the moment of inertia of the wheel, and $\alpha$ the angular acceleration you are trying to cause.

If you know the acceleration you are pushing the cart with, then use the geometric bond $$a=\alpha r$$ to find the angular acceleration, where $r$ is the wheel radius. The torque produced by the static friction forces is similarly just $$\tau=fr.$$ The moment of inertia of the wheel depends on the wheel mass, and you can probably compute it as $$I=\frac12 mr^2.$$ With all this put together, you should be able to solve for the static friction force $f$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149018/discussion-on-answer-by-steeven-is-static-friction-is-considered-in-case-of-trol); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.